# Is a constant function considered to be an entire function?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Is a constant function considered to be an entire function?

Constant function is differentiable everywhere.  Liouville's theorem holds for them too.

Comment: Not voting to close because this is a clear question with a clear and valid answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, constants are holomorphic in the entire complex plane.